# Jest test on typescript file syntax error: "interface is a reserved word in strict mode"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, next.js

*My Branch:* https://github.com/Futuratum/moonholdings.io/tree/JestTests

*Current PR:* https://github.com/Futuratum/moonholdings.io/pull/29

[image]

**My Astronaut.tsx component**

```
import React from 'react';

import { moonHoldings } from '../../shared/models';
import { astronaut } from '../../styles';

const { AstronautContainer, Heading } = astronaut;

interface LogoCheck {
  showLogo: boolean;
}

export default (showLogo: LogoCheck) =>  (
  <AstronautContainer>
    { showLogo.showLogo === true ? <Heading>{moonHoldings}</Heading> : null }
    <img src="static/astronaut.png" alt="astronaut" />
  </AstronautContainer>
);
```

**The simple test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

import Astronaut from '../components/Astronaut/Astronaut.tsx';

describe('<Astronaut /> component', () => {
  console.log('Astronaut', Astronaut);
  describe('when rendering', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Astronaut showLogo={true} />);

    it('should render a component matching the snapshot', () => {
      const tree = toJson(wrapper);
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

> SyntaxError: /Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/moonholdings.io/components/Astronaut/Astronaut.tsx: interfaceis a reserved word in strict mode (8:0)

[image]

I tried changing strict to false in my tsconfig's `compilerOptions` but that did not help.

Anyone else run into this with Jest testing and Typescript?

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "moonholdings.io",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Moonholdings.io",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 7777",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8000",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "test-win": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& jest --watch",
    "heroku-postbuild": "next build"
  },
  "author": "Futuratum",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.2",
    "decko": "^1.2.0",
    "downshift": "^2.2.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-with-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.9",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "waait": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/next": "^7.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/zeit__next-typescript": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.7.1",
    "casual": "^1.5.19",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.next/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
      ".*": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

**My .babelrc file**

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "styled-components",
          {
            "ssr": true,
            "displayName": true
          }
        ],
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          {
            "legacy": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "styled-components",
          {
            "ssr": true,
            "displayName": true
          }
        ],
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          {
            "legacy": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "next/babel",
          {
            "preset-env": {
              "modules": "commonjs"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "styled-components",
          {
            "ssr": true,
            "displayName": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your typescript is not compiled. Do you use ts-jest?

Comment: I have that packaged installed, but how do you use it @Stramski

Comment: I have following snippet in my package.json => "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig_renderer.json"
      }
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/test"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/test-setup/test-setup.ts"
    ],
**"transform": {**
     **".(ts|tsx)": "ts-jest"**
**},**
    "testRegex": "(/test/.*)(.test.ts|.test.tsx|.test.js)$"
  },

Comment: @Stramski ok I tried adding your transform, and testRegex lines, but now it can't find any tests. `No tests found`.

Comment: Because my regex does not match your tests ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok after I added this `@babel/preset-typescript` into my presets, that error went away:

```
"test": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",  // <---
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-env": {
          "modules": "commonjs"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "styled-components",
      {
        "ssr": true,
        "displayName": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case just having the `@babel/typescript` preset does not work.
You could try the following:

1. Rename the failing test file to either `.ts` or `.tsx` depending on whether you have JSX in your test (in this case `Astronaut.test.tsx`)
2. Update your jest config [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#defaults) (in this case package.json), add

```
"moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "tsx"
],
```

Answer (score -2):

your const declarion does not have a variable name.
const variableName: Type = new Type()
or
const variableName: Type;
or
const variableName = new Type;

Comment: You mean this line? `const { AstronautContainer, Heading } = astronaut;` I'm destructuring both those variable names out of the astronaut styles file.