# Unexpected token "<" expected "{" when passing Interfaces to React Class Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, laravel-8

Ran into an issue in my Laravel 8/Babel/Mix/React/TypeScript environment where a regular React class component is producing a compile error, since I've migrated the project to TypeScript and started passing an empty props and simple state interface to the component.

I've tried passing empty JSON objects, commenting out various import statements, moving the `export default` call below the function, but no dice so far.

The compile error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/.../MyComponent.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "{" (10:54)

   8 | import { IState } from '../interfaces';
   9 |
> 10 | export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
     |                                                         ^
  11 |
  12 |     constructor(props:any) {
  13 |       super(props);
    at Object._raise (/Users/.../node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:796:17)
```

`MyComponent.jsx` snippet:

```js
import { IState } from '../interfaces';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, IState> {

    constructor(props:any) {
      super(props);
      this.state = dummyData;
    }
    ...
```

Simplified `interfaces.ts`:

```
export interface IState {
    tasks: {
        [key: string]: ITask
      };
    columns: {
        [key: string]: IColumn
    };
    columnOrder: string[];
}
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.ts', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss')(),
    ])
    .setResourceRoot("/") // This allows easy resource linking from React components
    .purgeCss({
        //enabled: mix.inProduction(),
        enabled: true,
        folders: ['resources', 'app'],
        extensions: ['html', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'php', 'vue'],
    });

mix.extend('customAdditions', function(webpackConfig, ...args) {
    webpackConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
});

mix.customAdditions();
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"],
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}],
    "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],   
    "jsx": "react",      
    "strict": true, 
    "noImplicitAny": true,   
    "moduleResolution": "node",  
    "esModuleInterop": true,   
    "skipLibCheck": true,    
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
    "watch": true,
  }
}
```

**Update 1: Additional Things Tried to No Avail:**

- Incrementally downgrading React version (running `yarn` in between package version number changes) down to 16.14.0
- After that didn't work, downgrading both `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` to their latest version 16 releases to match the downgraded react packages
- Running this scorched earth command: `watchman watch-del-all && rm -f yarn.lock && rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn cache clean && yarn dev`

Comment: your compiler is trying and failing to parse [Typescript's generics syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). what version of typescript are you using and what build command are you running?

Comment: Thanks @DanO for the input – you're exactly right it was a configuration issue with my `.babelrc` file. Appreciate the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: needed to swap `@babel/preset-react` in my `.babelrc` for `@babel/preset-typescript`, after adding those presets with `yarn add @babel/preset-typescript --dev`. Shoutout to [Leon Gaban's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54339336/8143105) for pointing me in that direction

The new `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"],
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}],
        "@babel/preset-typescript" // <--
    ]
}
```

This would also fix it if someone was experiencing the error `interface is a reserved word`... when declaring an interface right before their class component.

Comment: Should mark your answer as the accepted answer.